# Integrating spring project

Tags: spring, tomcat

I am having the spring dependent jars in Tomcat server library (tomcat/lib) and running the spring application with out  spring related jar files in classpath.

I have following jars in Classpath:

```
apache-logging
commons-base
commons-beanutils(etc..)
```

And some other spring related jars in Tomcat lib.
Is this design correct.

Comment: No. Package your libraries with your webapp, not in Tomcat lib.

Comment: In 99% of all cases you shouldn't put Spring libs in your tomcat/lib directory.

Comment: Can you please explain,why it is not correct.Because i am having only spring projects deployed in tomcat

Answer (score 0):

It can be correct by design only when you have a lot of applications uses same jars in one container and it will be really critical issue for you.

But in most case this design creates a lot of problem. For example:

- You can't change version of lib without reload container
- You can't use different versions in different applications
- Developers should add this lib in local tomcat dir. If you have a lot of developers change the version of some lib can cost a lot.

In the most case you will less benefits then problems, but it still depends what problem you want to solve by adding some of dependency as provided.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having all dependent jars in tomcat container or classpath, try to use a building tool like `maven` or `gradle` as [Lucemferre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2335489/lucemferre) mentioned you have update all the jars and resolve conflicts manually.

When you use a build tool like maven or gradle

1. tool takes care to load all the dependent libraries
2. keeps the versions updated
3. can isolate the dependencies
4. aids to structure the project
5. supports most of the plugins

Try checking it [here](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/java/spring/creating-spring-mvc-helloworld-using-maven-in-eclipse-tomcat)